# SDL_Surface undefined or NULL?

Tags: sdl

Does SDL_Surface default to 'NULL' when left undefined?

Comment: This is vague. Do you mean `SDL_Surface*` (pointer) instead of `SDL_Surface` and "uninitialized" instead of "undefined" ? If so, an `SDL_Surface*` is nothing else than a pointer to some type, so its value is undefined if not initialized.

Comment: You mean SDL_Surface* ?

Comment: What language you're using? C/C++, right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends.

It is a good practice to initialize variables. From what I've seen, Lazy Foo uses mainly SDL_Surface as following:

```
SDL_Surface* gCurrentSurface = NULL;
```

so gCurrentSurface is a pointer to SDL_Surface type. Leaving it uninitialized would have different results.

If gCurrentState is a global or static variable (it has static storage) then it will be initialized to NULL automatically. If it is a local variable in function, it would contain some random value from stack.

Comment: I wonder where you create pointers on the heap, apart from complex structures like 2D arrays in C.

Comment: Well, I was not-so-clear with my answer. Creating pointers on heap with malloc sounds weird and is vague. Malloc/new returns some heap address.

Comment: Thanky you! I think I understand now. I didn't realize there were differences between initializing variables and pointers.

Comment: If that helped you in some way, you can consider marking answer as accepted. Note that usually functions return NULL pointers when something went wrong and operations weren't successful. Therefore, when you check that returned pointer is not NULL you know that there were no errors.